# postgres invalid input value for enum ''

Tags: sql, postgresql

I use this syntax

```
UPDATE table SET     
row_with_enum_value = CASE WHEN ? = '' OR ? IS NULL 
THEN row_with_enum_value ELSE ? END
```

The idea is that if the user enters an empty or null value, it is ignored. But for enum
this doesn't work, postgres doesn't skip the invalid value ' ' even if it's not assigned, it's just in the condition. How to bypass it?

```
UPDATE table SET     
row_with_enum_value = CASE WHEN '' = '' OR '' IS NULL 
THEN row_with_enum_value ELSE '' END
                               ^ error
```

Comment: pretty sure you need some parentheses in there

Comment: What "^ error" do you get? I guess if the `table.row_with_enum_value` column is of enum type, it can't be assigned the expression of string type. Instead assign `null` (if nullable) or some fallback enum constant.

Comment: @TomášZáluský error in the title. In the backend, enum is a string type, so if the user doesn't specify it, it defaults to ""

Comment: Read the [CASE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-CASE) docs. In particular: "Note

As described in Section 4.2.14, there are various situations in which subexpressions of an expression are evaluated at different times, so that the principle that “CASE evaluates only necessary subexpressions” is not ironclad. For example a constant 1/0 subexpression will usually result in a division-by-zero failure at planning time, even if it's within a CASE arm that would never be entered at run time." So either drop the `ELSE` or populate it with a valid selection.